# Binding gridview from more that 2 tables

Tags: c#, sql, gridview

[I am trying to bind a gridview from a table and updation records in  another table]

Actually I have two sql tables, named mtblVehicle_Booking and mtblLog_Book. In both tables all columns are same but mtblLog_Book is having 2 more columns KM_Start and KM_End.

Actually I am binding the gridview from mtblVehicle_Booking table (which don't have KM_Start and KM_End columns). The other side I have given edit option in gridview, but when I need to edit this gridview , the colums KM_Start and KM_End should come in that gridview as editing form and after updating the gridview the updated information should be seen in the gridview.

How can I accomplish this.

you can take it as a Gridview bounded with one table but when it gets update this should be partially bounded with the other table with updated information and rest of the gridview should bounded with the first one.

Suppose if gridview is having 5 rows from table1 one and if I edit two rows for updation the table2 then the gridview should show these 2 rows from table2 and the rest rows from table1 which actually has bot been updated.

Answer (score 0):

So I have no idea what kind of data repository we are talking about but:

1) why not just bind to mtbLog_Book and reconcile the differences with mtbVehicle_Booking when you are done with the front end data updates?

2) or Join the two objects:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj1 = new List<SomeOBject1>();
        var obj2 = new List<SomeOBject2>();
        var randomData1 = new SomeOBject1 { Id1 = 1, SomeData1 = "one" };
        var randomData2 = new SomeOBject2 { Id2 = 1, SomeData2 = "two", End = DateTime.Now, Start = DateTime.Now };
        obj1.Add(randomData1);
        obj2.Add(randomData2);

        var bound = obj1.Join(obj2, o1 => o1.Id1, o2 => o2.Id2, (o1, o2) => new {o1, o2.Start, o2.End});

    }

}

public class SomeOBject1
{
    public int Id1 { get; set; }
    public string SomeData1 { get; set; }

}
public class SomeOBject2
{
    public int Id2 { get; set; }
    public string SomeData2 { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }

}
```

3) or Create the join in sql before pulling the data into your c#. (Sorry my sql code doesn't show up pretty for some reason)

```
Select vb.*,lg.start,lg.end from mtblVehicle_Booking vb join mtblLog_Book lg on vb.whateverKeyTheyShare = lg.whateverKeyTheyShare
```

4) or create a partial class on your mtblVehicle_Booking object with the two extra columns.  then reconcile the mtbLog_Book.